# Populating a list from async Task produces strange results

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app, a background task is supposed to get a media file from the phone and display its name, artist and its cover art if they are available.

Doing is on the UI thread caused the app to be very laggy, however, pushing this into an async task works smoothly, but sometimes produces incorrect results. The names are wrong, or the image is incorrect. Sometimes items double. I taped this here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVAvY6X5yr0.

I really dont know what I am doing wrong, but appearenlty, something is. This is what this all looks like:

```
private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
{
    string SongName = "";
    string ArtistName = "";
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    byte[] data = null;
    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();

    try
    {
        reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
    }
    catch
    {
        Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 77s9", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    await Task.Run(() => // cause problems with the reload
    {
        SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
        ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

        data = reader.GetEmbeddedPicture();

        if (data != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);

                requestOptions.InvokeDiskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.None);
                requestOptions.SkipMemoryCache(false);
                requestOptions.CircleCrop();
                requestOptions.CenterInside();
                requestOptions.FitCenter();

                ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh, data); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)
            }
            catch
            {
                Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 034c", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }   
    });

    ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
        vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

        try
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                Glide
                    .With(ctx)
                    .Load(data)
                    .Apply(requestOptions)
                    .Into(vh.CoverArt);

            }
            else // because recycler items inherit their stuff and if it is altered it just shows views were there shouldnt be any ... 
            {
                vh.CoverArt.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_musicalnote);
                vh.dr = null;
            }
        }
        catch {
            Toast.MakeText(ctx, "ERROR 034c", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    });
}
```

In short: I am setting up all variables I need for one item, then fill them inside an async task with content, and then set the content on UI thread.
Is this bad ?

Thank you

EDIT:

This is the init function of the recycler view:

```
    private void InitRecView()
    {

        if (ap.getFirstStart())
        {
            ShowTutorial(1);
            ap.saveFirstStart(false);
        }
        // Instantiate the adapter and pass in its data source:

        ImageView lnBg = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.background_recView);

        mAdapter = new PhotoAlbumAdapter(GetSortedListWithAllSongs(), this, dbSeekObj, seekObj, mAudioManager, this, lnBg);

        // Get our RecyclerView layout:
        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

        // Plug the adapter into the RecyclerView:
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.SetItemViewCacheSize(50);
        mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        mRecyclerView.DrawingCacheQuality = DrawingCacheQuality.High;

        mLayoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.ItemPrefetchEnabled = true;
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

And this is the PhotoViewHolder:

```
    public PhotoViewHolder(View itemView, List<MP3objectSmall> mp3Obj, Activity_Player act, MediaMetadataRetriever reader, DataBase db, List<SeekObj> seekObj, AudioManager audioManager, ImageView lnBg, Context ctx) : base(itemView)
    {
        // Locate and cache view references:
        SongName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);
        AristName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView2);
        lnContainer = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_cardview);
        CoverArt = itemView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.musical_note);

        this.mp3Obj = mp3Obj;
        this.act = act;
        this.reader = reader;
        this.db = db;
        this.seekObj = seekObj;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.audioManager = audioManager;
        this.lnBg = lnBg;


        lnContainer.Click += delegate
        {
            int pos = AdapterPosition;
            ClickEvent(pos, AristName.Text, SongName.Text, CoverArt, lnBg);
        };
    }
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with your recycler view. How did you set up the rows?

Comment: @Prexx see my update. Hope it helps!